# Finding domain and range

Tags: calculus, functions

I just started learning engineering functions and I'm now at Domain and range ..

I was trying this question -

$$\frac{x+\sqrt{x+1}}{2x-1} $$

I found the domain to be

1. $x$ less than $1/2$
2. $x$ more than $1/2$
3. $x$ more than or equal to $-1$

Now about finding the range ,

I'm having huge difficulty...

I thought spitting the fractions will help but it didn't . -

Is there any way to see how to get the range easily ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried watching YouTube videos on how to find the domain and range? Your domain is wrong and the best way to explain it is better seen than read.

Comment: Here’s a video: https://youtu.be/sbvSBH2Mo20

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\sqrt{x+1}\geq 0$ so $x=t^2-1$. Thus we have to find all $b\in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy equation:

$$\frac{t^2 +t-1}{2t^2 -3} =b$$

If you draw a graph of rational function $f(t) = \frac{t^2 +t-1}{2t^2 -3}$, for $t\geq 0$ you will see that the range is $(-\infty,{1\over 3}]\cup ({1\over 2},\infty)$.

Answer (score -1):

The domain is $[-1,+\infty)\setminus\{\frac{1}{2}\}$.

$f$ is continuous function on $\left(\frac{1}{2},+\infty\right)$, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}^+}f(x)=+\infty,$ $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$

and easy to see that the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ has no solutions.

Indeed, $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$ it's
$$\frac{x+\sqrt{x+1}}{2x-1}=\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$2x+2\sqrt{x+1}=2x-1$$ or
$$2\sqrt{x+1}=-1,$$ which is impossible.

Thus, $$f:\left(\frac{1}{2},+\infty\right)\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2},+\infty\right).$$

The case $x\in\left[-1,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is the similar:

$f$ is a continuous function on $\left[-1,\frac{1}{2}\right)$, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}^-}f(x)=-\infty$  and $f(-1)=\frac{1}{3}.$

Thus, $$f:\left[-1,+\frac{1}{2}\right)\rightarrow\left(-\infty,\frac{1}{3}\right).$$
Id est, the range is:
$$\left(-\infty,\frac{1}{3}\right]\cup \left(\frac{1}{2},\infty\right).$$
Done!